# Get the all site collections in an online 365 Tenant

Tags: office-365

I am trying to write JavaScript to get all the site collections in an online 365 Tenant for a Sharepoint Hosted App.

I found this but I need to do it in JavaScript.

```
    public DataTable GetAllSiteCollections(string url)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("URL");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            SPWebApplication webApplication = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri(url));
            foreach (SPSite site in webApplication.Sites)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { site.Url, site.Url });
            }
        });

        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to do this, it could accomplished via SharePoint Search JSOM/REST API as demonstrated below

```
function searchSites()
{
    var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'";
    return $.getJSON(requestUrl)
    .then(function(result){
        return result.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.map(function(r){
           return {
              "Title": r.Cells[3].Value,
              "Url": r.Cells[6].Value  
           } 
        });
    });
}
```

Usage

```
searchSites()
.then(function(info){

    info.forEach(function(item){
       console.log(item.Url);    
    });

})
.fail(function(error){
   console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
});
```